# Two times froeign key from the same table

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have a problem to query such design

[image]

I need select this information (student_beginner, student_finalYear, project). The problem I have, in the "student_project" table are just integers from the primary keys from "student" and "project" tables. In the Result must be the actual values from "student" and "project" tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t know exactly what do you mean. I will try to guess:

Do you mean this:

```
Select student_beginner, student_finalYear, project from student_project
```

This will select the fields you want.

On the other hand, this query returns the project's name intead of project's ID:

```
Select sp.student_beginner, sp.student_finalYear, p.project_name 
FROM student_project sp 
JOIN project p ON sp.project = p.id
```

Or you can this in order to JOIN the three tables. Note that in this case I'm also returnin the student's ID.

```
Select s.name, sp.student_beginner, sp.student_finalYear, p.project_name 
FROM student_project sp 
JOIN project p ON sp.project = p.id
JOIN student s ON sp.id = s.id
```

Comment: So I have just the project name, but I need also the student name from student tables

Comment: you can get the student's name by writing s.name  in your select statement. Look at the query above.

Comment: But now I got the same name, it must be 2 name in the same row

Comment: Ok I got it, I must join the table student 2 time to get two different names from the same table.